# Can I save my progress in GTA 5 and load it again when I have a gamertag and when I am NOT connected to XBOX Live?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

> Can i load **Grand Theft Auto 5** save game and story mode in XBOX 360 without internet if i have a gamer tag and when i am offline and not connected to the internet??

Comment: This question is very poorly worded, which will make it hard to answer. It would be helpful if you could explain things individually and clearly. 1.) What was your account status when you started playing? 2.) What was your internet status when you started playing? 3.) What is your account status now? 4.) What is your internet status now? 5.) Why you anticipate a problem? (Don't respond to this comment, edit your question above. Also, drop the the > box quote. You're not quoting anybody.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure GTA 5 and GTA Online aren't linked together and you can play offline all you want. The story should be saved on your console and load from there, its only few KBs anyway (the save file size).

Comment: What I 'actually' want to know is that can I load the **story mode** when i am not connected to xbox live(i had internet connection but i don't have it right now. as i was connected to xbox live, i now have a gamer tag and i am registered in xbox live) PLEASE HELP ME!!!